# How would one save end user changes to UITabBarController (Swift)?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6

I am a developer in training and have been working extensively with storyboard in order to create a fairly simple TabBarController based application. I have assigned tags (values 0-10) to 11 different views in the tab, and am trying to figure out how to make it so that the position of the views in the tabBar are saved when edited by the user. Right now, every time the app is started the, position of the tabs resets, even if changed by the user under the "more" tab automatically added by Xcode. I have started out by adding

```
func tabBarController(_tabBarController: UITabBarController!, didEndCustomizingViewControllers viewcontrollers: [AnyObject]!, changed: Bool){

if changed{


}
```

to my app delegate. I am not sure how I would implement such a seemingly simple feature, and would appreciate any help. I am programming in Xcode 6.1.1, on Mac OS 10.10.2, and coding in swift.

Thanks

Comment: Simplest way to persist data is using NSUserDefaults. You can write out which tab user is looking at when the app goes into the background. If this makes no sense to you then I'd suggest getting one of the many 'teach yourself iOS' books and work through it before embarking on anything too ambitious.

Comment: I would suggest creating a class named something to the effect of "DataManager" that's a singleton to help you store the data. This way you can access that singleton from any class to access the data.